# ViewPager2: How to prevent the creation of fragments from interferring with the swipe animation?

Tags: android, android-viewpager2

I have a **ViewPager2** with a **FragmentStateAdapter** and an offscreen page limit of 1:

```
viewPager.setAdapter(new MyFragmentStateAdapter(this));
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);

public class MyFragmentStateAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {

    MyFragmentStateAdapter(@NonNull Fragment fragment) {
        super(fragment);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
        return new ItemFragment(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 15;
    }

}
```

What happened:

- I observed that every time I swipe on the view pager there's a **stutter** in the swipe animation. So I started investigating.

What I discovered:

- I found out that new offscreen fragments in ViewPager2 are created **at the beginning** of the swipe gesture (while the now deprecated ViewPager created them **at the end** of the swipe gesture).
- It doesn't matter what the value of setOffscreenPageLimit is (except if your intention is to load all fragments at once). The problem happens every time the view pager needs to create a new offscreen fragment.

Why this is a problem:

- That means that the creation of fragments will always **interfere** with the swipe animation, basically defeating the purpose of setOffscreenPageLimit (however, if your fragments are very lightweight you may not notice the problem).

Question:

- Is there a way to force ViewPager2 with FragmentStateAdapter to create offscreen fragments **at the end** of the swipe animation (like the deprecated ViewPager did)?

Comment: Hello @jmart, did you ever find a fix for this. Thanks.

Comment: @Jack Not yet, but I opened an issue on the issue tracker (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150626937) and it was accepted, so I guess we'll have to wait until a new version of ViewPager2 is released.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Yeah I am facing this too. It stutters each time i swipe and data loads as soon as I swipe so obviously it "janks"

Comment: @jmart, did you find a solution for this issue? I'm currently circumventing it by having a postDelayed-Handler in place with 300ms delay when calling notifyDataSetChanged(), but this seems to me like a hack. Below solution with onPageScrollStateChanged makes no difference in my case. I can clearly see in Perfetto trace that the swipe animation starts (fragment #1 -> #2) and then gets shortly interrupted by fragment (#3) data being refreshed (notifyDataSetChanged) on the UI thread.

Comment: @Patrick Not yet. I'm still using the original ViewPager. The issue I opened on the issue tracker is still labeled as 'Assigned', but with a low priority.

Answer (score 2):

My solution:

```
        view_pager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(object :
        ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
        override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {
            super.onPageScrollStateChanged(state)
            when (state) {
                SCROLL_STATE_IDLE -> {
                    view_pager.offscreenPageLimit = 1
                }
                SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING -> {
                    view_pager.offscreenPageLimit = OFFSCREEN_PAGE_LIMIT_DEFAULT
                }
            }
        }
    })
    view_pager.offscreenPageLimit = 1
```

Set `offscreenPageLimit = OFFSCREEN_PAGE_LIMIT_DEFAULT` when `SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING` prevent create next fragment on swipe gesture. And after swipe gesture set `offscreenPageLimit = 1` cause creating next fragment